# TypeError: Class.function is not a function at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, runtime-error, javascript-objects, strategy-pattern

***Strategy Pattern: interfaceBridge.js***

```
    // START IMPORT NODE HUE API
    var hue = require("node-hue-api"),
    HueApi = hue.HueApi,
    lightState = hue.lightState;
    var displayResult = function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    };

    var displayError = function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    };


    var host = "192.168.2.129",
    username = "033a6feb77750dc770ec4a4487a9e8db",
    api = new HueApi(host, username),
    state = lightState.create();

// END IMPORT NODE HUE API

var Bridges = function() {
  this.bridge = "";
};

Bridges.prototype = {
    setBridge: function(bridge){
      this.bridge = bridge;
    },

    showAllLights: function() {
    },

    getStatusOfLamp: function(id){
    },

    setLightState: function(id, state){
    }

};

var Phue = function() {
    this.showAllLights = function() {
      api.lights(function(err, lights) {
        if (err) throw err;
        displayResult(lights);
      });
    },
    this.getStatusOfLamp = function(id){
      api.lightStatus(id, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        displayStatus(result);
      });
    },
    this.setLightState = function(id, state){
      if(state == 'on'){
        api.setLightState(id, state.on(), function(err, result) {
             if (err) throw err;
             displayResult(result);
        });
      } else {
        api.setLightState(id, state.off(), function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          displayResult(result);
        });
      }

    }
};

var Wemo = function() {
    this.showAllLights = function() {
        //@String from Belkin WeMo API
    },
    this.getStatusOfLamp = function(id){
      //@String from Belkin WeMo API
    },
    this.setLightState = function(id, state){

    }
};

var TcpConnect = function() {
    this.showAllLights = function() {
        //@String from TCP Connect API
    },
    this.getStatusOfLamp = function(id){
      //@String from TCP Connect API
    },
    this.setLightState = function(id, state){

    }
};

module.exports = {
    Bridges: Bridges,
    Phue: Phue,
    Wemo: Wemo,
    TcpConnect: TcpConnect
};
```

***server.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var Bridges = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Bridges;
var Phue = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Phue;
var Wemo = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Wemo;
var Tcpconnect = require("./interfaceBridge.js").TcpConnect;

// Initialising of objects

var bridges = Bridges;
var phue = Phue;
var wemo = Wemo;
var tcpconnect = Tcpconnect;
bridges.setBridge(phue);



var PORT = 4333;
app.get('/lights/all', function (req, res) {
  bridges.showAllLights();
});

app.get('/lights/:id/state', function (req, res) {
  var id= req.params.id;

  bridges.getStatusOfLamp(id);
});

app.get('/lights/:id/state/:state', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var state;

  bridges.setLightState(id, state);
});
var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);

});
```

I recieve the following  error.

```
TypeError: bridges.setBridge is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jensgryspeert/Documents/STAGE/Raspberry Rest API/server.js:12:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:972:3
```

I can't find what the problem is. Hope someone could help me out.
It's based on Strategy pattern where Bridges is mine interface. Classes that use the subclass are Phue, Wemo and TcpConnect. For some reason he can't see mine objects. Even the are added in the server.js.

Comment: `var bridges = Bridges` does not looks like Initializing of objects. Perhaps it should be `new Bridges()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange usage of `modules.exports`. In **interfaceBridge.js**, You can dismiss the outer `;function(){...}();` and exports like:

```
modules.exports = {
    Bridges: Bridges,
    Phue: Phue,
    Wemo: Wemo,
    TcpConnect: TcpConnect
};
```

or

```
exports.Bridges = Bridges;
exports.Phue = Phue;
exports.Wemo = Wemo;
exports.TcpConnect = TcpConnect;
```

Then require in **server.js**:

```
var Bridges = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Bridges;
var Phue = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Phue;
var Wemo = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Wemo;
var TcpConnect = require("./interfaceBridge.js").TcpConnect;
```

Comment: Like I typed down @madox2 I still recieve the same problem.

Comment: You should use it like `var bridges = new Bridges();`.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting instance of `Bridges` instead of class.

```
module.exports = new Bridges(); // exporting instance of Bridges
```

You should export a class/function instead:

```
module.exports = Bridges;
```

UPDATE: furthermore you need to export/import correctly. You can export only one object per module. In your example you can export one object which contains all of your functions:

```
module.exports = {
    Bridges: Bridges,
    Phue: Phue,
    Wemo: Wemo,
    TcpConnect: TcpConnect
};
```

and then import it:

```
var Bridges = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Bridges;
var Phue = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Phue;
var Wemo = require("./interfaceBridge.js").Wemo;
var Tcpconnect = require("./interfaceBridge.js").TcpConnect;
```

Comment: @JensXel try to change it for all of your exports and run it outside of self-executing annonymous function (`;(function(){ ...`)

Comment: I've changed the begin post to what I've got now. Still the same error I recieves.